# is it possible to have input type:"color" readonly?

Tags: html, input

```
<input type="color" readonly name="favcolor">
```

This doesn't work.
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`readonly` wouldn't really make sense for a colour picker.

I think you probably want `disabled`

```html
<input type="color" disabled name="favcolor">
```

Comment: Disagree - I'd love if the color picker would still open (but readonly) so you can copy various values from it, just like a readonly text field. A disabled input makes it not clickable and does not open the picker.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this myself. It seems that this is an unknown bug, but you just can't use them together. I think the fault goes to the browsers.

I believe that readonly does make sense with a color picker, you just have to have all of the color picker readonly. So you should still be able to see and copy the values on the color picker screen, but not change them.

Of course there are always workarounds for this. If you just want to see the color, use disabled.

If you want to see the color, send it in the post, but not have it editable, use disabled and on form submit just enable it or use a hidden field that has the value.

If want to be able to copy the values, you can display the rgb values or html color code (#FFFFFF) on the page so it can be copied. Alternatively you can create a custom copy-to-clipboard button to copy the html color code to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<input type="color"  name="favcolor" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having an input `disabled` also removes it from form variables to be posted (GET/POST).
Another option to make it readonly and 'enabled' without the possibility of change is adding a style to invalidate pointer events `pointer-events: none` and prevent keyboard focus (`tabindex="-1"):

`<input type="color"  name="favcolor" style="pointer-events: none" tabindex="-1">`